# How i implement Mid-Point/Bresenham circle algorithm in objective-C?

Tags: iphone

I want to implement mid-point/Bresenham circle drawing algorithm using objective for Iphone.please give me any tutorial or source code to drawing mid point/Bresenham circle algorithm.It is possible to draw the circle using CGPoint method?

Comment: Have you searched if there's implementation in C or C++? You can use C and C++ for iPhone development. (With Monotouch you can use C# too.)

Comment: Have you read the documentation on this? http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/

Comment: KennyTM, 
I was searching implementation in C on http://www.sourcecodesworld.com/source/show.asp?ScriptID=901.
But i goes so much confusing.
Is there any valid raster graphics method in iphone using objective-C.

Comment: Johan Kool,
I want to draw the circle using CGPoint context and mid-point circle drawing algorithm.

Answer (score 4):

That algorithm appears to be well documented on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm), however, since it is about where to put the dots to create the circle, I have to point out the answers to [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313018/how-do-i-draw-a-point-using-core-graphics). Short summary: Core Graphics isn't pixel oriented.

So if you want to draw the circle point-by-point yourself, look at the answers for the linked question, and apply that to the algorithm from Wikipedia. If you just want to draw a circle, refer to the documentation, esp. `CGContextAddEllipseInRect`.

Comment: Johan Kool, 
I want to implement the following function for to draw the circle,
void CGContextStrokeLineSegments (
   CGContextRef c,
   const CGPoint points[],
   size_t count
);


GContextBeginPath (context);
for (k = 0; k < count; k += 2) {
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, s[k].x, s[k].y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, s[k+1].x, s[k+1].y);
}
CGContextStrokePath(context);

How can i implement that code. I was spending a lot of days for searching and implementation of those functions but i can't able to do that please help anyone................