# Drawing from dictionary pixel by pixel from one image to another with same coordinates

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, uicolor, cgpoint

I'm trying to copy from image 1 to image 2 pixel by pixel, and I save the data from the image 1 in dictionary: `[UIColor:CGPoint]`.

How to draw on CGContext all points pixel by pixel with the exact color for certain pixel on the image 2 at the same CGPoint?

```
@IBAction func save(sender: UIButton) {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(100, 50))
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    for (color,point) in dict{
        drawPixel(context!, startPoint: point, color: color.CGColor)
    }
    testIV.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
}

func drawPixel(context:CGContextRef, startPoint:CGPoint, color:CGColorRef){
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
    CGContextSaveGState(context)
    CGContextSetLineCap(context, .Square)
    CGContextBeginPath(context)
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, color)
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0)
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, startPoint.x + 0.5, startPoint.y + 0.5)
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, startPoint.x + 0.5, startPoint.y + 0.5)
    CGContextStrokePath(context)
    CGContextRestoreGState(context)
    })
}
```

I've tried like this but the image is empty...

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show some code of your own, where you want to draw.

Comment: I've copy the pixels from photo and I want to draw it on another photo on the same place

Comment: Yes, what have you tried in regards to the drawing?

Comment: nothing I don't know how to draw it pixel by pixel I just have the information with the pixels. I want to draw the information from image 1 to image 2 on the same pixels

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/313018/how-do-i-draw-a-point-using-core-graphics

Comment: CGContextFillRect
CGContextDrawPath
CGContextStrokePath 
which of this function draw the pixel and how to define the color and SET IT on the image 2 ?

Comment: google for a tutorial for coregraphics, I will not give you a complete introduction here.

Comment: okay tell me only how to add the drawn pixels on to image 2 ?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/HandlingImages/Images.html

Comment: what is the function that draws the pixel ?

Comment: **READ THE TUTORIAL**

Comment: I read it and still I can't do it... I don't know how to set the color of the pixel and I don't know how to add it on image 2 at the same position....

Comment: How is a dictionary mapping unique colors to one point each going to help you, unless you want to copy only images where each color occurs in only one pixel?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the call to `dispatch_async`. You want your drawing code to run immediately, but `dispatch_async` causes it to run later on, long after the rest of your `save` method has finished.

```
func drawPixel(context:CGContextRef, startPoint:CGPoint, color:CGColorRef){
    CGContextSaveGState(context)
    CGContextSetLineCap(context, .Square)
    CGContextBeginPath(context)
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, color)
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0)
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, startPoint.x + 0.5, startPoint.y + 0.5)
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, startPoint.x + 0.5, startPoint.y + 0.5)
    CGContextStrokePath(context)
    CGContextRestoreGState(context)
}
```

(This is also a really inefficient way to do things, but you'll figure that out soon enough...)

Comment: Which ones? Is there anything different about those points compared to the rest?  You will need to debug that on your own.

Comment: okay I fixed it now how to put it back on the image 2 at the same position from which I take the pixels ?