# Most efficient way to draw a huge number of tiny dots in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, drawing

I am entirely new to iOS, and for my first project I am trying to make a [chaos game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaos_game) app, which naturally requires a large number of points be drawn. Ideally, I need 10^5 to 10^6 individual pixel points for the illustrations.

This is a performance concern. Right now, I am using `CGRect` with very small height and width, is there a less expensive way to do this?

I dont need to draw all of the dots at once, but I do need them to appear on screen over a reasonable period of time to show the progression of the emerging fractal.

Comment: I would use a `UIGraphicsContext` for this.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/313713/1971013) perhaps?

Comment: you can use CAEmmiterLayer to acheive this